# real dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, discrete-time

I am a bit confused on how to solve this system or generally these kind of systems 
$$x(t+1)= x(t) -2y(t)$$
$$y(t+1) = 2x(t) +y(t)$$
My confusion derives from that fact that I am working with $(t+1)$ we did these kind of tasks with derivatives and differential equations earlier.

Comment: Set $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$, then $z(t+1)=(1+2i)z(t)$ is just a geometric sequence.

Comment: @Lutz Thank you, but how do you get to this? Can you tell me what I can google to find books and similar on the topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system you have considered is in the class of **Discrete-Time, Linear Time Invariant** systems. That is discrete time systems of the form
$
z[k+1] = A z[k].
$
where $A$ is a real matrix. Given an initial condition $z[0]\in\mathbb{R},$ such systems have closed form solutions of the form
$$
z[k] = A^{k} z[0]
$$
Under some appropriate conditions on $A$ you can easily find simpler expressions. For example, defining the state vector $z = (x,y)^\top,$ your system is solved by
$$
z[k] = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^k z[0]
$$
Your matrix $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ which connects with the observation made by @Lutz. In particular if we define a new state
$$
w = \begin{pmatrix} i\sqrt{2} & -\sqrt{2}\\ -i\sqrt{2} & -\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix} z
$$
we find the dynamics reduce to
$$
w[k + 1] = \begin{pmatrix} (1 + 2i) & 0 \\ 0 & (1 - 2i) \end{pmatrix} w[k],$$
which admits solutions of the form
$$\begin{aligned}
w[k]
&= \begin{pmatrix} (1 + 2i)^k & 0 \\ 0 & (1 - 2i)^k \end{pmatrix} w[0]\\
&= 5^{\frac{k}{2}}\begin{pmatrix} e^{i\theta k} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\theta k} \end{pmatrix} w[0]
\end{aligned}$$
where $\theta = \arctan(2).$ If $A$ is not diagonalizable, you can still find a change of coordinates that puts the matrix in Jordan Normal Form. This technique generalizes for higher dimensional discrete time systems.